# Defining similar, but not equal variables in one line

Tags: python, loops, variables, tkinter, iteration

As an example for my question, I am producing buttons on a screen. All buttons will have the exact same command, but they will be placed at different coordinates in the window (using tkinter). Using the same method of defining variables such as:

```
apple, banana, pear = "fruit"
```

How could I define buttons, each with the same dimensions and commands, but with a coordinate that is incremented.
If I was to define these buttons one by one it would look like this...

```
Button1 = Button(root, text= "Button", height = 1, width = 1, command = command, x = 20, y = 50)
Button2 = Button(root, text= "Button", height = 1, width = 1, command = command, x = 40, y = 50)
Button3 = Button(root, text= "Button", height = 1, width = 1, command = command, x = 60, y = 50)
```

But is there a way to define these buttons using something similar to a loop?
Thanks.

Comment: The `Button` class doesn't support an `x` and `y` argument. How do you expect those coordinates to be used? Are they row/column values? pixel values?

Comment: I was just using it for a quick example to get the general idea

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with unpacking. (Your first example, by the way, raises a `ValueError`.)

```
Button1, Button2, Button3 = [Button(root, text="Button", height=1, width=1, command=command, x=x, y=y)
                               for x,y in [(20, 50), (40,50), (60,50)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a list:

```
buttons = []
for p in [(20,50),(40,50),(60,50)]:
    buttons += [Button(root, text= "Button", height = 1, width = 1, command = command, x = p[0], y = p[1])]
```